# Using strings as axis tick labels with Plotly (Blazor) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, charts, plotly, blazor

I've been trying to use strings as axis tick labels with (Blazor) Plotly chart in C#, but doesn't seem to work. It works fine with simple numerical labels. Current source code looks as follows:

```
    PlotlyChart chart;
    Config config = new Config();
    Layout layout = new Layout();

    IList<ITrace> data = new[]
    {
        new Scatter
        {
            Name = "ScatterTrace",
            Mode = ModeFlag.Lines,
            X = new List<object>{"1", "2", "3"},
            Y = new List<object>{1,2,3}
        }
    };
```

Then adding some more data to the chart through a button press:

```
        if (!(chart.Data.FirstOrDefault() is Scatter scatter)) return;
        var y = ts.GetColumn(0).ToArray().Cast<object>().ToList();
        var x = Enumerable.Range(0, y.Count).Cast<object>().ToList();
        var tickText = ts.Time.Select(x => x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).Cast<object>().ToList();

        var xAxis = new XAxis
            {
                TickVals = x,
                TickText = tickText,
                Type = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.TypeEnum.Category
            };

        layout.XAxis = new List<XAxis>();
        layout.XAxis.Add(xAxis);
        await chart.ExtendTrace(x, y, data.IndexOf(scatter));
```

The chart data shows up but still only with simple numerical x axis values. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding TickFormat on your axis instead of adding tick values.

```
    layout = new Layout
    {
        XAxis = new List<XAxis>
        {
            new ()
            {               
                TickFormat = "%d/%m/%Y",
            }
        }
    }
```